# How to remove price amount from Virtuemart Custom field?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a website where I have used joomla with virtuemart. I have added a custom field Where field type is Cart Variant. But problem is I don't want to display the price in the drop down select option. You can see it from this screen short (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCx3a.jpg) or (http://awesomescreenshot.com/011ih9ue8)

I want to remove the red mark item. Anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long try I got the solution. I am using joomla 2.5.7 & virtuemart v2.0.12. Just follow this:

Go to:
administrator/components/com_virtuemart/models/customfields.php  & find the following line it may be line number 871:

```
$productCustom->text = $productCustom->custom_value . ' ' . $price;
```

Delete `. $price` & that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific, this issue is related to virtuemart, the best way to get an answer is to ask it on official site forum.virtuemart.com.

What version of joomla and virtuemart are you using?

On Back-end in virtuemart configuration you can set not display price, have you tried this?

If this won't work, you will probably need to make template override, usually located in components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default_showprices.php

Without more info I'm not able to answer your question better.